# jQuery Syntax: Using a variable to target an id

Tags: jquery, syntax

I'm trying to do the following but keep failing:

I have a variable:

```
var targg = "new-house";
```

And I would like to use the value of the variable to target the element with that id:
However I'm trying to do that inside a set of parameters and it does not work.

Here is the final Code:

```
var targg = "new-house";
$(this).someFunction({
 para1: true,
 para2: "string",
 para3: "#"+targg
});
```

This however works:

```
$(this).someFunction({
 para1: true,
 para2: "string",
 para3: "#new-house"
});
```

It is probably very easy but I cannot find it!!
Hope that it is clear.
Thanks

Comment: This should work. Have you missed anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(this).someFunction({
 para1: true,
 para2: "string",
 para3: '#'+ targg +''
});
```

Comment: @theCodeParadox - can you explain why adding the empty string is necessary? To me it should make no difference.

Answer (score 0):

This

```
var id = '#' + targg
$(id)
```

targets the proper selector.

Either you don't have an element with such an id, or you aren't calling it correctly in your someFunc().

See relevant fiddle:

```
http://jsfiddle.net/njyXZ/5/
```

Comment: I've tried all that but it did not work :( It has been confusing me.